# Load C++ dll in CSharp with correct datatypes

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

Need to load this C++ method from a DLL in CSharp and I'm wondering which datatypes I have to use?

```
WORD FunA (BYTE Num, BYTE *pFrameTX, DWORD nbbitTX, BYTE
*pFrameRX, DWORD *pnbbitRX)
```

My first approach was:

```
[DllImport("Example.Dll")]
public static extern UInt16 FunA(byte Num, Byte[] pFrameTX, UInt32 nbbitTX, ref Byte[] pFrameRX, ref UInt32 pnbbitRX);

Byte[] toSend = new Byte[1], toReceive = new Byte[1024];
toSend[0] = 0x26;
UInt32 numberOfBitsReceived = 0;

FunA(Convert.ToByte(1), toSend, 0, ref toReceive, ref numberOfBitsReceived);
```

What's wrong here? Can someone help me to find the correct datatypes and calling usage?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[DllImport("Example.Dll")]
public static extern UInt16 FunA(byte Num, IntPtr pFrameTX, UInt32 
nbbitTX, IntPtr pFrameRX, ref UInt32 pnbbitRX);

// ...    

Byte[] toSend = new Byte[1], toReceive = new Byte[1024];
toSend[0] = 0x26;
UInt32 numberOfBitsReceived = 0;

// reserve unmanaged memory for IntPtr
IntPtr toSendPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(toSend[0])*toSend.Length),
    toReceivePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(toReceive[0])*toReceive.Length);

// copy send buffer to Unmanaged memory
Marshal.Copy(toSend, 0, toSendPtr, toSend.Length);

// call C++ DLL method
FunA(Convert.ToByte(1), toSendPtr, 0, toReceivePtr, ref numberOfBitsReceived);

// copy receive buffer from Unmanaged to managed memory
Marshal.Copy(toReceivePtr, toReceive, 0, numberOfBitsReveived/8);

// free memory
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(toSendPtr);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(toReceivePtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you missed the ref modifier in front of pFrameTX.

```
[DllImport("Example.Dll")]
public static extern UInt16 FunA(byte Num, ref Byte[] pFrameTX, UInt32 
nbbitTX, ref Byte[] pFrameRX, ref UInt32 pnbbitRX);
```